# Schema conflict when storing dataframes with datetime objects using load_table_from_dataframe()

Tags: pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, pyarrow

I'm trying to load data from a Pandas `DataFrame`s into a BigQuery table.  The `DataFrame` has a column of dtype `datetime64[ns]`, and when I try to store the df using `load_table_from_dataframe()`, I get

> google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Provided Schema does not match Table [table name]. Field computation_triggered_time has changed type from DATETIME to TIMESTAMP.

The table has a schema which reads

```
CREATE TABLE `[table name]` (
  ...
  computation_triggered_time    DATETIME  NOT NULL,
  ...
)
```

In the `DataFrame`, `computation_triggered_time` is a `datetime64[ns]` column.  When I read the original `DataFrame` from CSV, I convert it from text to datetime like so:

```
df['computation_triggered_time'] = \ 
  df.to_datetime(df['computation_triggered_time']).values.astype('datetime64[ms]')
```

**Note:**

The `.values.astype('datetime64[ms]')` part is necessary because `load_table_from_dataframe()` uses PyArrow to serialize the df and that fails if the data has nanosecond-precision.  The error is something like

> [...] Casting from timestamp[ns] to timestamp[ms] would lose data

Comment: Can you give an example of the format of  'computation_triggered_time' in the dataframe?

Comment: @Bobbylank: see Issue
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/6542

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a problem with Google's google-cloud-python package, can you report the bug there? https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python